# What is the difference between the so-called confusion matrix and contingency table? Are they the same?

Tags: contingency-tables, confusion-matrix

I would like to understand the difference between the confusion matrix and contingency table in the context of classification (Machine Learning). It seems that different sources use their names for the same matrix. Am I wrong?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix - the confusion matrix "is a special kind of contingency table, with two dimensions ('actual' and 'predicted'), and identical sets of 'classes' in both dimensions"

Comment: Contingency tables are used to describe data, and confusion matrices are used to describe the performance of classifiers.